# How to make result set from ('1','2','3')?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question, how can i make a result set making only list of values. For example i have such values : `('1','2','3')`
And i want to make a sql that returns such table:

```
1
2
3
```

Thanks.

[Edit]

Sorry for wrong question.
Actually list not containing integers, but it contains strings.
I am currently need like ('aa','bb,'cc').

[/Edit]

Comment: Do you want to pull these values out of an existing table, or create a table that would store them?

Comment: I would like to make intersection with theese values. actually i want to find all values that are NOT in the table, but exists in correspoding list.
I am using oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I've found is using XML.

```
SELECT items.extract('/l/text()').getStringVal() item
FROM TABLE(xmlSequence(
        EXTRACT(XMLType(''||
        REPLACE('aa,bb,cc',',','')||'')
          ,'/all/l'))) items;
```

Wish I could take credit but alas : http://pbarut.blogspot.com/2006/10/binding-list-variable.html.

Basically what it does is convert the list to an xmldocument then parse it back out.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to write a SQL statement which will take a comma separate list and generate an arbitrary number of actually rows the only real way would be to use a table function, which calls a PL/SQL function which splits the input string and returns the elements as separate rows.

[Check out this link](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/2222781/Returning-Rows-Through-a-Table-Function-in-Oracle.htm) for an intro to table-functions.

Alternatively, if you can construct the SQL statement programmatically in your client you can do:

```
SELECT 'aa' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'bb' FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'cc' FROM DUAL
```

Comment: UNION is a nice solution. But i thought there should exist more elegant one. Thanks !

Comment: If you already know the values are distinct, it would be preferable to use UNION ALL.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to abuse a table that is guaranteed to have enough rows.

```
-- for Oracle
select rownum from tab where rownum < 4;
```

If that is not possible, check out [Oracle Row Generator Techniques](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques).

I like this one (requires 10g):

```
select integer_value
from   dual
where  1=2
model
  dimension by ( 0 as key )
  measures     ( 0 as integer_value )
  rules upsert ( integer_value[ for key from 1 to 10 increment 1 ] = cv(key) )
;
```

Answer (score 1):

One trick I've used in various database systems (not just SQL databases) is actually to have a table which just contains the first 100 or 1000 integers. Such a table is very easy to create programatically,  and your query then becomes:

```
SELECT value FROM numbers WHERE value < 4 ORDER BY value
```

You can use the table for lots of similar purposes.

Comment: you probably want to add an ORDER BY